# Android EXIF orientation always returns 1

Tags: android, camera, orientation, exif

I'm trying to rotate the image obtained from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to show it always on landscape mode. The problem that I'm facing, is that `EXIF Orientation` is always 1, independently from the orientation where I take the photo.

The code is the following:

> Where I take the photo

```
private fun takePhoto(option: Int)
{
    val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val photoFile = File.createTempFile("ID_Card_", ".png", storageDir)

    when(option)
    {
        SCAN_ID_CARD_FRONT -> front_id_card_path = photoFile.absolutePath
        SCAN_ID_CARD_BACK -> back_id_card_path = photoFile.absolutePath
    }

    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            photoFile.also {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, option)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Where I try to check the image orientation

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
{
    when (requestCode)
    {
        SCAN_ID_CARD_FRONT ->
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                val imageBitmap = fixImageRotation(front_id_card_path)
                id_card_front.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun fixImageRotation(file: String): Bitmap
{
    val imageFile = File(file)
    val exif = ExifInterface(imageFile.absolutePath)
    val orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL)
    val imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file)

    return when (orientation)
    {
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> rotateImage(imageBitmap, -90)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotateImage(imageBitmap, 90)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotateImage(imageBitmap, 180)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotateImage(imageBitmap, 270)
        else -> imageBitmap
    }
}
```

The value `orientation` is always 1. I'm doing something wrong or missing something?